# How to trigger this quest in Fallout 3?

Tags: fallout-3

I was playing the other day and I was west of Megaton, ahead of where the road splits into two, below a cliff I encountered 3 nonhostile wastelanders, upon talking to them, they mentioned about going for a treasure north I believe, then they turned hostiles and tried to kill me.

I managed to kill them and didn't check the new marker on my map, sadly I was low on health before this and a giant radscorpion ambushed me not far from there and killed me.

Sadly I didn't save for quite sometime and when I tried to find these guys I failed to do so. It was nighttime but I don't know around what time when I encountered these guys.

Does anybody know how to trigger these guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The encounter you describe sounds like a unique encounter pointing you to the location "Oasis", where there is a major quest, of the same name.**

[The Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_3_random_encounters#Quest-related) lists this encounter as "Oasis Raiders", but basically, 2-4 raiders are encountered, who accidentally reveal the location of a "treasure", before turning hostile.

This treasure is actually the location, itself. Just head north, as you are, and look for a bunch of trees. I have provided a map snippet, below. The encounter only acts as a "pointer". You do not get anything special for having met these raiders, prior to discovering Oasis. They are simply a means to point you towards a major quest.

[image: Oasis marker on the Fallout 3 map]

If you have played previous Fallout games, it may interest you to know that you will run into Harold, here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into the right direction, I wish I could trigger this event again though. Do you know how?

Comment: I do not believe there is any requirement for the encounter, apart from not having a pointer to Oasis, or having started the quest Oasis. Is there any particular reason you wish to trigger the event, again? If it is, in fact, Oasis, I would highly recommend just heading straight for the location. It's a really good quest, along with some really great rewards and achievements.

Comment: No especial reason, I just don't like to miss on things

Answer (score -2):

I believe that these people are completely randomly generated. If you have saved the game before meeting them, you may see them if you trace your steps to them.

Comment: while there are random encounters with hostile wastelanders, OP reports a map marker being placed on the map. Map markers are only placed for unique encounters, which in themselves usually act as a means to point the player towards a location/event/quest they have yet to discover.